# IE error on page tab redirect

Tags: javascript, facebook, tabs

I'm using the following code to redirect a user from the "Add Tab to Page" popup to their facebook page.

```
    function addToPage() {
      // calling the API ...
      FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'pagetab'
        },
     function(response) {
            if (response != null && response.tabs_added != null) {
                $.each(response.tabs_added, function(pageid) {
                      window.location = 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/abc-123/' + pageid + '/?sk=app_251008564974830';
                });
            }
        }
      );
  }
```

The code works in all browsers but IE, which gives me the following error:

> API Error Code: 100
>   API Error Description: Invalid parameter
>   Error Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted

I need the page to redirect to their Facebook page, not my app. If I put a redirect_uri in then it redirects to the app, which is not the functionality I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: I've tested it using IE9

Answer (score 0):

You could try to encode the url you are passing using either of the 3 javascript encoding methods:

```
encodeURIComponent(url)
/* or */
encodeURI(url)
/* or */
escape(url)
```

References:
[encode comparisons](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)
[encodeURIComponent on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)